# Add opacity to background-image CSS for hero cover

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to do away with my second div/class `opacity` and add the opacity to the image using CSS on the `hero` class?

```css
.hero {
  background-image: url('https://cdn10.bostonmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/03/nkotb.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.hero .opacity {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="opacity">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean you want to avoid using `.opacity` and instead apply the opacity effect on the background image directly on `.hero`?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple background images, which are [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) by all modern browsers.

```css
.hero {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%),
      url('https://cdn10.bostonmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/03/nkotb.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">Some content</div>
```

Comment: This works great except that if I add content to the div to sit on top of the hero image, it actually sits behind the opacity layer.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't realise that was a requirement. In that case, see my updated answer.